# What is the best approach to sort 2 large text files in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, large-files

I am building a simple java application that involves reading information from a csv file. The information in the csv file comes in this form:

```
"ID","Description"
"AB","Some sort of information for AB"
"AC","Some sort of information for AC"
```

I am required to let user print out the description, the id, or both, in a console sorted by ID. The simplest solution would be to parse the files with a CSV library, such as opencsv, and put these string in a TreeMap, and print the content of the TreeMap. The key in the TreeMap would be the ID, and the value is the description.

However the CSV file could be huge. It could be 5 GB, and loading 5GB of strings into a TreeMap would cause an out of memory error. To handle large files, I could sort the files using an external merge sort. Once, I get the sorted file, I could print out the content of the file into the console by simply reading the file.

An external merge sort will definitely be much slower than loading the content of the file into a TreeMap. I am considering to detect the file size. If the file size is more than the available memory, then I will use an external merge sort. Otherwise, I will load the content of the file into the TreeMap.

However, this would mean there will be two separate block of codes that perform 2 different sorting. Therefore increasing the amount of code that need to be maintained. If you would write this application would you consider writing 2 separated codes code that would handle a small csv file, and a big csv file separately. Or would you just sort the file using an external merge sort irregardless of the file size ?

Or is there an alternative to this approach ?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a design question that may lead to debate and multiple valid proposals. It may be a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com. I've voted to close here as "not constructive".

Comment: @DuncanJones Hi, I am more than happy to migrate this to programmers.stackexchange.com. Once I figure out how to do that

Comment: @DuncanJones although I have 824 reputation in stack overflow, I only have 113 reputation at programmers.stackexchange.com. This could be the reason why I can't migrate this question to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much. You have a good answer. If this is closed a "not constructive", it probably won't be deleted. For future reference, migration is achieved by flagging the question for moderator attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse the csv file yourself, adding only the ID column to the `TreeMap`, as value record the byte length up to that line. Afterward for printing use a `RandomAccessFile` to read the corresponding lines. If this approach still overflows your memory, take a look at [MapDB](https://github.com/jankotek/MapDB). It provides TreeMap implementations that seamlessly overflow to disk and has great performance.

Comment: thank you for informing me about MapDB. I will explore that API for my program :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends your boss / client how much time resources are allocation for this. If this isn't a problem, than of course need to have an optimized version with 2 part of the code: for quick memory sort for smaller files and for large files the external sort.

When the client want a quick solution, than you can ask him: you want a slow solution wich will work with unlimited file size or do you want a faster running solution which has a memory limit? - and you will get the response as he want and for he it will be fine :) -for you too if the client satisfied.

Maybe he want an implementation: if the software isn't payed fully, than it will allow only files with max 1GB and so on.